# is there an idiomatic way to route elements which fail in a TransformBlock within a TPL dataflow graph?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

I am using TPL dataflow to create a bufferBlock of input elements which are processed by a TransformBlock that outputs to an output bufferBlock

```
inputQueue = new BufferBlock<InputPacket>;
processQueue = new TransformBlock <InputPacket, OutputPacket>;
outputQueue = new BufferBlock<OutputPacket>;

inputQueue.LinkTo(processQueue, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });
processQueue.LinkTo(outputQueue, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });
```

Is there an idiomatic way to route elements which fail?

When *`InputPacket`* elements complete processing, the action associated with
*`processQueue`* will return an *`OutputPacket`* which will be routed to the *`outputQueue`*

If the action associated with *`processQueue`* calls an unreliable webservice,
then processing of some *`InputPacket`* elements will timeout, 
and I would like to retry these elements *x* times. But I don't want to try them immediately, I want to put them back on the input queue.

I would like to be able to route the *`InputPacket`* elements which 
timeout back into the *`inputQueue`* until they have failed *`x`* times and then to *`failureQueue`* :

```
BufferBlock<CallPacket> failureQueue = new BufferBlock<InputPacket>;
```

Using `LinkTo` predicates is complicated by the two different types involved:

```
InputPacket OutputPacket
```

I looks like I *could* handle this by changing:

```
processQueue = new TransformBlock <InputPacket, ParentPacketType>;
```

and then writing predicates based on the type of the packet.

or

by storing the output in the inputElement as a member of `InputPacket`,

but neither seem a **good** way to achieve this.

Comment: this project contains LinkSubTypeTo which seems to be for this purpose: https://github.com/gridsum/DataflowEx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I think your terminology is confusing and you should stick with the one used by TPL Dataflow. The dataflow graph is not composed of queues, it's composed of *blocks*. And those blocks process *data elements* not blocks.

Now, when TPL Dataflow does not provide you a block that does what you want, one solution is to build that block yourself, out of the provided blocks. A simple version of that could look like this:

```
public static IPropagatorBlock<TInput, TOutput> CreateRetryTransformBlock<TInput, TOutput>(
    Func<TInput, TOutput> transform, int retryCount,
    ITargetBlock<(TInput, Exception)> failureBlock)
{
    var failedInputs = new Dictionary<TInput, int>();

    TransformManyBlock<TInput, TOutput> resultBlock = null;

    resultBlock = new TransformManyBlock<TInput, TOutput>(
        async input =>
        {
            try
            {
                return new[] { transform(input) };
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                failedInputs.TryGetValue(input, out int count);

                if (count < retryCount)
                {
                    failedInputs[input] = count + 1;
                    // ignoring the returned Task, to avoid deadlock
                    _ = resultBlock.SendAsync(input);
                }
                else
                {
                    failedInputs.Remove(input);
                    await failureBlock.SendAsync((input, exception));
                }

                return Array.Empty<TOutput>();
            }
        });

    return resultBlock;
}
```

Assumptions I made:

- You can use C# 7.0. If not, the features I used are easy to replace.
- It's fine to ignore all but the last exception. Otherwise, the `Dictionary` would have to store all the previous exceptions and then send them to the `failureBlock`.
- It's fine to send the failed data element back to the same block. If not, the method would have to take one more parameter and use it for that.
- The block doesn't need to support parallelism. If it does, you would have to make the code thread-safe (you would probably start by using `ConcurrentDictionary` instead of `Dictionary`).
- The input data elements can be stored in a dictionary (read: their `GetHashCode` behaves correctly) and there will be no duplicate inputs. Otherwise, you would have to devise some other mechanism to count retries.

Comment: I'm going to work on this approach, if it works for me I'll come back with the tick, cheers compound